# Whats the reasoning behind not allowing a derived class's concrete property that implements an interface's interface property?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a very simple example.

```
public interface IMyInterfaceProperty
{
}

public class MyProperty : IMyInterfaceProperty
{
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterfaceProperty SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public MyProperty SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In this example `MyProperty` is derived from `IMyInterfaceProperty` but is not allowed.  What was the thought process behind not allowing this to compile?

`Program.MyClass` does not implement interface member `Program.IMyInterface.SomeProperty`. `Program.MyClass.SomeProperty` cannot implement `Program.IMyInterface.SomeProperty` because it does not have the matching return type of `Program.IMyInterfaceProperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the following is not allowed:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterfaceProperty SomeProperty { get; set; }
    MyProperty SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I think the reason is that members with the same signatures are not allowed in the type. And return value is not considered here:

> The signature of a method specifically does not include the return
>   type, nor does it include the params modifier that may be specified
>   for the right-most parameter.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx. Though it is for VS2003, I don't think that has been changed since those times :) )

Comment: to be implemented method should have the same signature and return value. if you need different return values you may use generics: `T SomeProperty { get; set; }`

Comment: This was more in reference to ASP.Net MVC as the default model binder cannot create an interface on my class to populate it's values (thus in my constructor I have to populate my interface with a concrete class manually instead of allowing MVC to instantiate the class for me.)

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not type safe.

If `MyClass` implements `IMyInterface`, then an instance of `MyClass` needs to be able to work in an `IMyInterface` variable (Liskov Substitution Principle).  Let's see what that means:

In addition to the types you've defined, we also assume:

```
public class EvilProperty : IMyInterfaceProperty {}

public static class X
{
    public static void EvilMethod(IMyInterface a, IMyInterfaceProperty b)
    {
        a.SomeProperty = b;
    }
}
```

Now, here's the call (brace yourself!):

```
X.EvilMethod(new MyClass(), new EvilProperty());
```

See what will happen?  The method will assign the instance of `EvilProperty` to the `MyClass` instance's `SomeProperty`, but that property expects a `MyProperty`, and `EvilProperty` doesn't inherit from `MyProperty`.